# Can i change path of TestTools.UITest.Dll in wpf?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Hi sorry for that question but, it is possible to change location reference OF TEST dll???

I have VS 2015 enterprise, i copy all DLL test in my subversion folder, add the reference but VS don't change the path... the path is alwais :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.****.dll

could you help me please?

[path issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N7mL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've discovered is to collect your required .dlls and package them together using NuGet. Then you can change your project references to the NuGet package rather than those in the default installation.

So: Yes, change your .csproj files (unless you're working in .NET Core)