# Can I build a CodedUI test solution using msbuild on another pc?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, coded-ui-tests

I have VS2015 Enterprice edition( which is required to compile CodedUI projects - correct me if i'm wrong).

The projects has some CodedUI unit tests.

1) I **can** build the solution on my Dev PC in VS2015 - no problem.
2) I **can** build the solution on my Dev pc using msbulid.exe solution.sln - no problem.
3) I have another PC (test pc) where there is **NO** Visual studio, only Build Tools and .Net frameworks are installed.  When I try to build the solution using msbuild.exe - **there are errors related to Test Tools**:

```
Assertion\Assert_WPF.cs(6,40): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My question: Is it possible at all to build the solution that includes CodedUI (which is only included in Enterprise edition)  on a test machine, where no VS is installed?

Comment: what about this issue according to the Ryanman`s suggestion ? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue as well. It's very [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511711/can-i-change-path-of-testtools-uitest-dll-in-wpf/39798369#39798369).

When you install VS Enterprise you're also installing the CodedUI .dlls into your Global Assembly Cache. This is what allows UI Tests to run. Your project on your dev machine references these.

If you try to run them elsewhere they'll search for these .dlls and not find them.

You have two options:

1. Spend the ~$3k on an enterprise license for the machine you want to build the tests under
2. Create a nuget package (Or an equivalent solution) that contains the necessary codedUI .dlls. Update your project to reference this package rather than the GAC (Note that this is fairly difficult). Ensure the package is deployed along with your solution when building to the machine without enterprise.

You also may be able to shotgun the codedUI .dlls into your other machine's GAC using Gacutil but I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting in such an old question, but I ran into the same problem yesterday.

Ryanmans answer might be correct but there is another workaround to that problem that I found. If you take a look inside the relevant .csproj file you will find something similar to this:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
</Choose>
```

As you can see the references are only being used when a specific visual studio version is used. Now if you use msbuild you will see exactly the errors you did. Because the references are actually missing.
The workaround is to assign the project in question a symbol for conditioinal compiling. (Rightclick --> Properties). 
You can than use that symbol  as a parameter in the msbuild command like so:

```
/p:DefineConstants="YourSymbolName" /t:Rebuild
```

This fixed these errors for me and our build server builds the project just fine.